# Парсер на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    nickname = soup.find('div', class_='biguser').text
    return nickname


def main():
    url = 'https://forum.dirt.ru/member.php?u=1'
    print(get_data(get_html(url)))
```

---

Почему возвращает пустое значение? Извините за глупый вопрос.

Comment: Может, надо полный путь указать в BS? Скопировал код из видеоурока - все равно возвращает пустое значение.

Comment: Используйте `rs.content` вместо `rs.text`,  `rs.content` возвращает байты, а `BeautifulSoup` сам сможет определить кодировку страницы. Да и можно использовать вместо `lxml` -- `'html.parser'`, тот хотя бы стандартный в питоне, в отличии от `lxml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрел на том сайте и не нашел `class` `biguser`, зато есть `bigusername`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://forum.dirt.ru/member.php?u=1'

rs = requests.get(url)
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

nickname = root.select_one('.bigusername').text.strip()
print(nickname)
# "Dronix"
```